# How to align limits of double integrals?

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment

I'd like to have the limits of two integrals vertically aligned.

In this example, the `x` and `b` should be positioned on the same line.

```
\[\int\limits_x^{\infty}\int\limits_b^{\infty} x^2+y^2 \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y \]
```

[image]

Has anybody an idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One way is to use `\vphantom{b}` with `x`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[\int\limits_{\vphantom{b}x}^{\infty}\int\limits_b^{\infty} x^2+y^2 \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

With some beautifications as per the comments of Mico:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand*\diff{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\begin{document}
\[\int\limits_{\vphantom{b}x}^{\infty}\!\!\int\limits_b^{\infty} x^2+y^2 \,\diff x \, \diff y \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Aah, you beat me by a few seconds to this answer... :-) Real quick: I would also recommend placing parentheses around the integrand, tightening the space between the two integral symbols by inserting `\!` (negative thinspace), and adding `\,` (positive thinspace) between the integrand and the variables of integration.

Comment: @Mico And also between the variables of integration: `\,dx\,dy` is what you find in the TeXbook all the times.

Comment: @Mico I was improving the speed my *two* finger typing lately and it is the first time I was faster :-) Thanks for the comments and I edited the answer.

Answer (score 14):

Another possible method is to use an invisible strut like `\mathstrut`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
\usepackage{physics}

\begin{document}
  \[
    \int_{x\mathstrut}^{\infty}\int_{b\mathstrut}^{\infty} x^2+y^2\,\dd x\,\dd y
  \]
\end{document}
```

For other formatting options the »[physics](http://ctan.org/pkg/physics)« package is quite helpful.

---

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Place a `\strut` in each limit, so your example becomes

```
\[\int\limits_{x\strut}^{\infty}\int\limits_{b\strut}^{\infty} x^2+y^2 \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y \]
```

A `\strut` is an invisible box of zero width but the same height and depth as (I think) an parenthesis.

Comment: Note that strut doesn't get smaller in subscripts so this does align them but leaves more space than the other two answers