# How to get limits aligned?

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment, amsmath, math-operators

Assume the following MWE/Screenshot. How to get the "limits" x and y correctly vertically aligned?

I tried already: `\mathstrut` and `\vphantom{g}` as discussed in [How to align limits of double integrals?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145589/how-to-align-limits-of-double-integrals) but not a lot of luck.

[image]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\argmin}{\operatornamewithlimits{argmin}}
\newcommand{\bla}{\operatornamewithlimits{blabla}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\argmin_{x...} \bla_{y...} .....
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In additions see `\adjustlimits` from mathtools.

Comment: @daleif - I anticipated your suggestion with my answer. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\argmin}{\operatornamewithlimits{\mathstrut argmin}}
\newcommand{\bla}{\operatornamewithlimits{\mathstrut blabla}}
\begin{equation}
\argmin_{x...} \bla_{y...} .....
\end{equation}
\renewcommand{\argmin}{\operatornamewithlimits{argmin}}
\renewcommand{\bla}{\operatornamewithlimits{\vphantom{\mathrm{g}}blabla}}
\begin{equation}
\argmin_{x...} \bla_{y...} .....
\end{equation}
\renewcommand{\argmin}{\operatornamewithlimits{\smash{\mathrm{argmin}}}}
\renewcommand{\bla}{\operatornamewithlimits{blabla}}
\begin{equation}
\argmin_{x...} \bla_{y...} .....
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. So you need to use \mathstruts in the line itself, and not in the 'limits' part.

Comment: @jos -- you need the `\mathstrut`s on *both* the line itself and in the limits.  easy to demonstrate by using, say, a *d* as a limit.

Comment: Hmm, `\operatornamewithlimits` has become `\operatorname*` several years ago.

Comment: @egreg thought I didn't recognise it but copied from OP:-)

Answer (score 6):

Instead of modifying the macros `\argmin` and `\bla` to include math-struts, I suggest you load the [mathtools](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mathtools) package -- a superset of the `amsmath` package -- and use that package's `\adjustlimits` macro to align the expressions in the limits.

*Remark*: As @egreg has noted in a comment, the instruction `\operatornamewithlimits` has been deprecated for quite a few years. I suggest you use `\DeclareMathOperator*` instead.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}% for "\adjustlimits"
\usepackage{amsfonts} % for "\mathfrak"
% Use "\DeclareMathOperator*" instead of "\operatornamewithlimits"
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min} 
\DeclareMathOperator*{\bla}{blabla}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\text{without \texttt{\string\adjustlimits}:} \quad
&\argmin_{x\in\mathfrak{X}} \bla_{y\in\mathfrak{Y}} \dots\\
\text{with \texttt{\string\adjustlimits}:} \quad
&\adjustlimits\argmin_{x\in\mathfrak{X}} \bla_{y\in\mathfrak{Y}} \dots
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. But, please, also fix it with `\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}` (the `\,` is better, in my opinion) and similarly for `\bla`. Note that `\operatornamewithlimits` has been deprecated several years ago in favor of `\operatorname*`.

Comment: @egreg - Thanks! I've implemented both of your suggestions.

Comment: `\arglimits`? Typo in your text?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have TL installed, but this should work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\argmin}{\operatornamewithlimits{argmin}}
\newcommand{\blawithdepth}{\operatornamewithlimits{bla\vphantom{g}bla}}
\newcommand{\bla}{\operatornamewithlimits{blabla}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\argmin_{x...} \blawithdepth_{y...} .....
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Use `\bla` where it's fine, and `\blawithdepth` where you want the limits to align. However, I would recommend simply keeping them unaligned.

Comment: I use something similar for `\cos`: I have some situations where a symmetry with `\sin`, which has an ascender; I'd not generally add struts to operator names otherwise.